# How do I save text from a UITextField in a UITableViewCell?

Tags: uitableview, cocoa-touch, textfield

I have a sectioned table with dynamic number of rows per section. In each cell there is a text field. I need some advice or a nudge in the right direction for: saving text input in the text field after editing is done into a NSMutableArray. .

Comment: Use an `NSDictionary` instance with index paths as keys if you are unsure of the number of rows per section.

Comment: I don't follow. Can you clarify? All I'm looking for is a way to identify which row's textield was edited.

Comment: How are you setting up the cell?

Comment: Custom UITableViwCell in IB loaded into the table view via cellForRowAtIndexPath method. It has 1 text field hooked up in IB as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming you are setting the table view controller as the text field's delegate somewhere. Based on the comment, you can identify the cell the text field belongs to using,

```
- (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
    YourCustomCell * cell = (YourCustomCell *)textField.superview.superview;
    NSIndexPath * indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForCell:cell];

    /* Use the index path to store the data in array or dictionary with the index path as key */
}
```